# SwiftLint Rule for pragma mark

Tags: regex, swiftlint

I'm trying to implement custom swiftlint rule to track when before "// MARK:" is less than two new lines. I'm not good in regex. Here is my rule:

```
    custom_rules:
pragma_mark:
name: "Wrong pagma mark format"
regex: "([^\n\n]?\/\/ MARK:)"
message: "Please leave two lines before // MARK:"
severity: warning
```

but this regex is wrong. what I do wrong? Maybe swiftlint has already this rule? But I can't find it

Comment: See for yourself: https://regexr.com/3o9hq

Comment: You need a negative look-behind. Using `[^\n\n]` says "Match one character that is either a `\n` nor ` \n`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a negative-look behind. Here's a starting point:

```
(?<!\n\n)\/\/ MARK:
```

And here is a [RegExr](https://regexr.com/3o9l0) page that explains how it works, and offers some test cases.

You'll probably want to make this case insensitive, and be tolerant for white space before and after the "MARK".

Comment: Not working for me:(

`    }\n
}\n
// MARK: Header Extension\n
extension FilterViewController {`

No warning there. Maybe custom rule is formatted wrong?

Comment: Make a regexr page with the failing test cases and post it here.

Comment: @SeverynKatolyk Oops, I had it negated. I had a positive lookbehind (`(?<= ... )`), not a negative look behind as needed (`(?<! ... )`). Fixed! https://regexr.com/3ohcj